# GCC Shared Library Linkage

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries

I'm using GCC to create both a shared library (.so) and an application to run on an Cortex-M4 microcontroller.

If I compile the library as a static library and then compile the main application (with the library), everything compiles and the result is a single (but fairly large in size) binary.

When I change the library over to shared and then recompile both this and the main application, the linking phase throws up numerous errors:

`Invoking: Cross ARM C++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g3 -T "C:/Users/workspace.kds/MyProject/Project_Settings/Linker_Files/linker.ld" -Xlinker --gc-sections -L"C:/Users/workspace.kds/MyProject/Project_Settings/Linker_Files" -L"C:\Users\workspace.kds\MyLibrary\Debug" -Wl,-Map,"MyProject.map" -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs -o "MyProject.elf"  ./Sources/main.o  ./Project_Settings/Startup_Code/startup.o   -lMyLibrary
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: section .dynamic loaded at [00011d28,00011ddf] overlaps section .romp loaded at [00011d28,00011d4b]
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20140731 assertion fail /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/binutils/bfd/elf32-arm.c:7730
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: error: required section '.rel.plt' not found in the linker script
c:/freescale/kds_v3/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:58: recipe for target 'MyProject.elf' failed
make: *** [MyProject.elf] Error 1`

Or to cut this a bit shorter

`section .dynamic loaded at [00011d28,00011ddf] overlaps section .romp loaded at [00011d28,00011d4b]`

Does the shared library need to be compiled with the same linker configuration as the main application? If so, why does the static build of the same library work fine?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I would assume, it does. static library works fine because it is not even linked, this is just an archive or .o files.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The problem is, I can't find (via extensive Googling) any examples to show this working. I've just tried now using the same linker.ld file as my main application and even more errors have been raised and ends in the `required section '.rel.plt' not found in the linker script` as before

Comment: Ok, so after a bit more digging, GCC has a `-pie` option for "position independent code". Not quite sure to how apply this to my scenario but it's looking more promising.

Comment: "When I change the library over to shared..". We need to see the exact compile and link commands by which you compiling the object files contained in the shared library and linking them into that shared liubrary.